# Spring boot OnetoMany with JPA

Tags: java, rest, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I have started testing with spring boot to create a Restful webservice that has
simple crud functions.i have two entity classes

Company.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Company_new")
public class Company {

@Id
@NotNull
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;



public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@NotNull
@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="company",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<User> users;


public Company(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public Company(){

}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}
}
```

and User.java

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="user_new")
  public class User {
  @Id
  @Column
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int idUser;

  @NotNull
  @Column
  private String name;

  @NotNull
  @Column
  private String userName;

  @NotNull
  @Column
  private String authLevel;

  @Column
  private String password;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="idCompany")
  private Company company;

  // Public methods


  public Company getCompany(){
      return company;
  }

  public void setCompany(Company company){
      this.company = company;
  }




  public void setName(String name){
      this.name =name;
  }

  public void setUserName(String userName){
      this.userName = userName;
  }

 public String getName(){
     return this.name;
 }

 public String getUsername(){
     return this.userName;
 }

 public String getPassword(){
     return this.password;
 }


  public String getAuthLevel() {
    return authLevel;
}

public void setAuthLevel(String authLevel) {
    this.authLevel = authLevel;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setId(int idUser) {
    this.idUser = idUser;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public int getId(){
      return this.idUser;
  }




 }
```

i want to have a relationship with a Company having many users.
I have tried presisting a user record like this

```
@Autowired
CompanyDao companyDao;
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity createUser(@RequestBody User user) {


    try {
        Company c = companyDao.findOne(user.getCompany().getId());
        user.setCompany(c);
        userDao.save(user);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

my data is presisting in the database the way i want
but when i try to access a company record it loads like this

[image: respones]

obviously it loads relationships in a cycle and eventually gives stack overflow error. how to solve this ?

Comment: please add the error stack trace as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your desired outcome you can:

- use `@JsonIgnore` on `public Set<User> getUsers()` to prevent serializing the users collection or `@JsonIgnore` on `public Company getCompany()` to prevent company serialization
- use `@JsonManagedReference` on `public Set<User> getUsers()` and `@JsonBackReference` on `public Company getCompany()` to let Jackson know that it's a bidirectional relation.

*PS. If the API you're exposing will be consumed by code you do not control consider [not exposing entities directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943758/is-it-good-to-return-domain-model-from-rest-api-over-a-ddd-application) but [mapping them to DTOs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212384/exposing-domain-models-over-api?newreg=72bf10f30a2d4f6fbf864a096782f061)*

Comment: hi Miensol, Thank you very much for your time for answering this post. I am using this in a rest service. After adding the annotation  you used in the mention Copilation errors gone. But I am not able to see Users details in the rest response. Could you please help me on this?
Thank you.